# Why I get the following error: "returning reference to temporary [-Werror=return-local-addr]"

Tags: c++, class, c++11, return-by-reference

given the following code:

```
#include <set>

using std::set;

class Pool {
    set<int> s;
public:   
    typedef typename set<int>::iterator Iterator;
    const Iterator& begin() const {
      return s.begin(); //** error
    }
};
```

Why I get the following error (I understand the meaning of the error, but, I don't understand why I get it in this case)?

> returning reference to temporary [-Werror=return-local-addr]

How can I fix it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know that it's will fix the error (but I don't understand why I can't return by-reference in this case)

Comment: by not returning a reference to a temporary. `s.begin()` creates a temporary object and you return a reference to it. Iterators are usually passed by value as they are cheap to copy

Comment: @AlanBirtles So I can't return object from my set by reference (If I want to change it from the outside) ?

Comment: You can return a reference to an object (subject to the iterator invalidation rules) but you can't return an iterator by reference, you must return by value.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Can you show it in new answer please :) ? (I ask for `Iterator& begin();`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Returning reference to temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667161/c-returning-reference-to-temporary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `set<...>::begin` function returns its iterator *by value*. Since you do not store that value anywhere, it's a *temporary* value, and you can't really have references to temporary values.

The simple solution is for your function to *also* return by (non-const) value.

Comment: So how can I allow to change the objects in the set outside the class?

Comment: @SombreroChicken You right, but in my class exists more method that called `begin` and returns non-const by-reference (so, my question now it's about this method)

Comment: @MathQueus, the iterator internally references set<int> s, so returning by value and using the iterator, you are still working on 's'

Comment: @rmawatson But if I returns it by-value so it's only copy of the really element in the set, no?

Comment: You cannot change objects in set.

Comment: @MathQues, the iterator doesn't hold the value that is in the set, it is just a lightweight type for iterating over the set. Internally holding some kind of reference to the set that you are iterating over. When you dereference the iterator is when it accesses the set & its value.

Answer (score 2):

```
const Iterator& begin() const {
  return s.begin(); //** error
}
```

is illegal because the result of `s.begin()` is a temporary object and therefore you can't return a reference to it. Maybe if you look at this equivalent code it will be clearer?

```
const Iterator& begin() const {
  Iterator it = s.begin();
  return it; //** error
}
```

Returning a const reference to an iterator doesn't make much sense anyway as you wont be able to move the location that the iterator points to. You should always return iterators by value, this way the caller is free to make copies of the iterator and modify their location. For example if you could get your code to compile the following calling code would not work:

```
Pool p;
const Pool::Iterator& it = p.begin();
++it; //error it is constant
```

The user could fix their code by copying your returned reference into a new object:

```
Pool p;
Pool::Iterator it = p.begin();
++it; //no error
```

As your users wont be able to use the reference you can't return its  better just to return by value:

```
const Iterator begin() const {
  return s.begin();
}
```

Note that `std::set` is not like most other containers and doesn't allow modification of the values via its iterators: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin

> Because both iterator and const_iterator are constant iterators (and may in fact be the same type), it is not possible to mutate the elements of the container through an iterator returned by any of these member functions.