# Why am I getting "warning: returning reference to local temporary object"?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm getting `warning: returning reference to local temporary object` from clang compiler on code bellow and I'm not sure why. ([code on gdbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tENwDMpLegAyeWpgByxgEaZiXSwAdUCwuto9QxMzb19/OjsHZyM3D05LJRU1OgYCZmICIONTC0VlTFUAtIyCKKdXd09FdMzskLyFWrL7CtiqhIBKRVQDYmQOAHIpc3tkQywAanFzHXUm4kxmIxnscQAGAEENzYM/UUmGL0K8NgBJdGnzABFJg3sCc0kAfQIZ2S29%2B2BJgHkCBDuC5XW73ehPV7vHbQrbjZgKBSTAAKqAeklu4gA7B9Nl4DC5WHhkCAdpMyZM0LQmpgAB5eYjI1H0dEQdC9AmYSY00iTNn49iTACePKOJ3Ol2InUmtFQtIGXgIJK25JVqppzwgNO6Qo1gu1xA1kqxskx1xhmxVfI5FLoTSkADYuRApZSmtNsZNFgQ%2BrQuc93u6zcryVaBa63pJHYLnTaqQR3dJPZhvcRfYL/eZE1igxbyaLkKdWMDww7PTHwwmkynfQaA9nzfS8AA3ZgEDikkPsgXqqHBsmhznp3u5skV/OF4G1zPm%2BvTrbmuEIyYAMQMrFYzz0JEuxp2eIJRKVI9j1LpDNX683qG3rK7nO5vLvQpFxwL4s9PP%2BgOIwNYCilMpypgCpHqqYFcumxCajywqetqf4an%2BUq7qa5oqg8J4Ro6UEura8bGlWPoQc8xAAHQ4XWqF9pMGElpGkx/uWeGVl6REIZROZ7sQzatu21EViiaK3DSkHDiqFZfkClzsXO2yobJOwYUYzD2M6u7UReG5bsQlxUGurDGpwPKSDyliTNws44iqzAGEQmGlkYkEgpMenruRamySqrGppM6zDtmgzdKwICDAArIMpCmIM6wRagIU6HIciTAovT9JyIycBFirRYF3QANYgKFACcpGSEVoXcEVRXrJInChZG3CSKFQghdwEVRTFpBxYMEUKCA6ykNlMXdHAsAwIgKCoEYXh4OwZAUBAaDTbNVTAJwNWkFQs1tsQfUQC4IWdS49gZIKIWZaQS1GFoBC/LQrBnTlpBYMpojsIdEX4IsRRNpgfVPbShS2UMnUPMoH1CHgLjEKdehYOdWXcUYCPdDQ9BMGwHA8PwgjCKIKCJTIkMuH1kDdKgCoBP9vUFEUGgQNY9SmEZ1jlDEcSCD4fgpIE%2Bg5Jz4Q82zlTxPkyTFM0TOCEkhQ8yUmTC%2B0otNKUUtGSrCutOzHTdClfQDFwQUheFkUQ91NIABz2gAtPa3CTMAyDIJM62lZMEC4IQJDTJI5hGZMejLXNPt%2B1KCUyHIWUfZ0%2BWFQNwWDG1pDI6FA0dbFIW9f1g3R6Qo0Tb0BB4gQ5CUEtM1zYImD4EQoto4wLDvdjADuMNeCjLVhe1ZshRlkzN4QCBclbtv247zuu5IUc5THpCAswWAeM6ndJynac9z1ijZ0NuWkAV3DrKRmLrNwqfrEVmIW9wmLmKFmLNQn5jd093XT8NRuDFPpsv5nOcz90v1doBDMEAA%3D))

```
<source>: In member function 'const int& Full_Coord::r() const':

<source>:29:41: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]

   29 |     int const& r() const { return xy_r.r(); }

      |                                   ~~~~~~^~

<source>: In member function 'const int& Full_Coord::ls() const':

<source>:30:36: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]

   30 |     int const& ls() const { return ls_; }

      |                                    ^~~

Execution build compiler returned: 0

Program returned: 0
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using SpecialId = uint32_t;
using OtherId = uint32_t;


class Point2D {
public:
    constexpr Point2D(double x, double y, SpecialId r) noexcept:
            x_(x), y_(y), r_(r){}

    double const& x() const { return x_; }
    double const& y() const { return y_; }
    SpecialId const& r() const { return r_; }

private:
    double x_;
    double y_;
    const SpecialId r_;

};


class Full_Coord {
public:
    constexpr Full_Coord(double x, double y, SpecialId r, OtherId ls) noexcept:
            xy_r(x, y, r), ls_(ls) {}

    int const& r() const { return xy_r.r(); }
    int const& ls() const { return ls_; }

private:
    const Point2D xy_r;
    const OtherId ls_;
};

int main(){
    Full_Coord full{1, 2, 3, 4};
    auto const& my_r = full.r();
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried reading other SO questions related to this but most of them have a getter that returns a temporary from the function or a method. However, I'm not sure why is this also the case in the code above?

I wanted to return const ref to inner private members only for reading purposes.

Comment: Because you are returning a reference to a temporary object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning: returning reference to temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339601/warning-returning-reference-to-temporary)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is because the `SpecialId` and `OtherId` are `uint32_t`, and since your function returns `int` it must be implicitly cast so a temporary is created.

Either change the return types of `Full_Coord::r` and `Full_Coord::ls` to `SpecialId` and `OtherId` respectively, or use `auto` as a return type.

```cpp
auto const& r() const { return xy_r.r(); }
auto const& ls() const { return ls_; }
```

Comment: Note: Your compiler needs to be moderately up-to date (C++14 or better) to to get an `auto` return type this polite.

Comment: Yea. The question had the C++14 tag so I suggested auto.

Comment: Totally appropriate. That's a note for future readers who try this with older tools. I mean smurf. We're still getting Turbo C++ questions.

Comment: @user4581301 Borland C++ 3.1 is 1337!

Comment: After years of mucking around on the computer I bought to write philosophy papers when I should have been writing philosophy papers, I formally learned to program on Borland C++4.5. back in '95. Sadly I used it to learn C. Some things never change.