# c++ return rvalue as const left ref

Tags: c++, rvalue, const-reference

Since we can pass rvalue to function taking const left ref,

```cpp
void taking(const string& ref) {}

taking("abc");
```

can we return rvalue as const left ref without reporting warning?

```cpp
const string& returning()
{
    static string s = "abc";
    if (1)
    {
        return s;
    }
    else
    {
        return "xyz"; // warning: return-local-addr
    }
}

cout<<returning()<<endl;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning: returning reference to temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339601/warning-returning-reference-to-temporary)

Comment: Hi @Rana, I did know what happened for the warning. But my case is to add a return branch of rvalue to a function which returning const left ref. I think it is a little difference from your question.

Comment: Look closely at the question i gave link to. That question also have `if` `else` branch just like yours. The answers given there already explains what you have here. If/when you understand the cause of the warning there you will be able to understand it here as well and vice versa.

Comment: Hi @Rana, actually in my case, the function is derived from an interface. So it must return const left ref instead of a const value. I may keep a static variable in function, which takes some extra memory in this case

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not the value category (lvalue vs rvalue), but the fact that you return a reference at all.

It doesn't matter what kind of reference. When the function returns, the object that the return value is referencing, will be gone. In the case of `return s;` that is the local variable and in the case of `return "xyz";` it is the temporary constructed in the return statement (which must be constructed because `"xyz"` itself is not a `string` and so cannot be bound to `const string&`).

You must return-by-value:

```
string returning()
```

If you do so, then an expression of the form `returning()` will be a prvalue (a kind of rvalue) and can be used e.g. in a function expecting a `const` lvalue reference, which can also bind to rvalues.

```
taking(returning()) // ok!
```

This is ok, because the return value of the function itself is not destroyed when the function exits (that would be nonsensical). Instead it lives until the end of the full expression in which the function was called.

There are also no unnecessary copies of the object being made due to copy elision rules (except for an unlikely extra move operation in `return s;`).