# vector equals for type <std::string> works in g++ but not in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-c++, vector, g++, equals

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
std::vector<std::string> vector1;
int main() {
    vector1.push_back("adadad");
    std::vector<std::string> vector2;
    vector2.push_back("adadd");
    if (vector1==vector2) {
        std::cout<<"success";
    } else {
       vector1.swap(vector2);
       vector2.clear();
       vector2.push_back("adadd");
       if (vector1==vector2) {
           std::cout<<"success_swap";
       }
    }
}
```

Now this works in g++ but not in visual studio. The operator == doesn't work here and throws compilation error in visual studio 2010(ultimate). **The same works if the vector is of a integer type**.Am I missing something here ? This is not a linux native thing that they have omitted. Why there is a implementation in gcc but not in vc++ ?

The error message that it shows is:

```
[snip]\vc\include\xutility(2990): error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
          with
          [
              _Elem=char,
              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
          ]
          [snip]\vc\include\exception(470): could be 'bool std::operator ==(const std::_Exception_ptr &,const std::_Exception_ptr &)'
          [snip]\vc\include\exception(475): or       'bool std::operator ==(std::_Null_type,const std::_Exception_ptr &)'
          [snip]\vc\include\exception(481): or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::_Exception_ptr &,std::_Null_type)'
          [snip]\vc\include\system_error(408): or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_condition &)'
          [snip]\vc\include\system_error(416): or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &)'
          while trying to match the argument list '(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>, const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>)'
          with
          [
              _Elem=char,
              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
          ]
          [snip]\vc\include\xutility(3030) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool std::_Equal<_InIt1,_InIt2>(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _InIt1=const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> *,
              _InIt2=std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>
          ]
          [snip]\vc\include\xutility(3051) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool std::_Equal1<const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>*,_InIt2>(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,std::tr1::true_type)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Elem=char,
              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
              _Ax=std::allocator<char>,
              _InIt2=std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>,
              _InIt1=const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> *
          ]
          [snip]\vc\include\vector(1489) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool std::equal<std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>,std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>>(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,
              _InIt1=std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>,
              _InIt2=std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>>
          ]
          [snip]\test\main.cpp(8) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool std::operator ==<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>(const std::vector<_Ty> &,const std::vector<_Ty> &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ty=std::string
          ]
```

Comment: I confirm the error happens for visual studio

Comment: In the future, please post the full error message from the "output" window.  Not the "error" window, though even that would have been better than nothing

Comment: @MooingDuck sorry about that. I expected error in all versions of visual studio. will remember that

Comment: Keep in mind that not all of us want to start up visual studio and build your code to answer a question.  I frequently answer questions on my phone, so if the full error message isn't there, I can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because in MSVC, `std::string`'s equality operator (`==`) is *not* included by `<iostream>` or `<vector>`.  You have to include `<string>` as well.

The key line in the message is; "error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Comment: There is a point that string doesn't actually come as a built in data type in standard types rather a separate class and so we would need that. But why g++ accepts it in the first place? Where is this implementation in g++ ? What is the reason behind this varying implementations ?

Comment: Basically, either iostream or vector header includes the file containing basic_string, but not <string>. I have no idea which.  It could be something like iostream includes exceptions which includes basic_strings or something.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a really old compiler.

This works for me in MSVS 2005, which isn't that new itself.

If your compiler is `C++03` compliant, it should work:

> 23.2.4
>
> ```
> template <class T, class Allocator>
> bool operator == ( const vector<T,Allocator>& x,
>                    const vector<T,Allocator>& y);
> ```

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual studio 2010 ultimate !!! Strange that you say it works in 2005 itself. It worked for integer type ones but not for string in mine. Strange..strange !!