# converting command line arguments program to menu driven program

Tags: c++

I did a program that took command line arguements to run it. I am now trying to do a menu drive program as part of its "improvement." I used,

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

in the original where the arguements were:

```
char * startCity = argv[1];
char * endCity = argv[2];
in.open(argv[3],ios::in); //<----file name went here
```

Here is what I did now and I know it is incorrect:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

int menuChoice;
string startCity;
string endCity;
string fileName;
ifstream in;

cout<<"Welcome to J.A.C. P2\n"
  "\n"
  "This program will find the shortest path\n"
  "from One city to all other cities if there\n"
  "is a connecting node, find the shortest path\n"
  "between two cities or find the shortest\n"
  "between three or more cities.\n"<<endl;

cout<<"Please make a choice of what you would like to do:\n"<<endl;

cout<<"  1------> Shortest Path between 2 cities.\n"
      "  2------> Shortest Path between 3 or more cities.\n"
      "  3------> Shortest Path from 1 city to all.\n"
      "  9------> Take your ball and go home!\n"<<endl;
cout<<"Waiting on you: "; cin>>menuChoice;

switch (menuChoice) {
    case 1:
        cout<<"Enter the starting city: ";
        cin>>StartCity;
        cout<<"\nEnter the ending city: ";
        cin>>EndCity;
        cout<<"\nEnter the name of the file: ";
        cin>> fileName;

    break;
```

Since all of my program is based on char * argv[] How can I convert those into strings OR how can I assign variables to the arguements in order to read them in?

I appreciate all the answers but they seem to be going in the direction I am trying to get away from. The OLD program used command line arguements. How can I do this:

```
string StartCity = char * argv[1];
string EndCity = char * agrv[2];
string filename = in.open(argv[3],ios::in);
```

That is what I am trying to do. I am sorry if I did not make myself clear.

Comment: `string s = argv [0];` Is that what you mean for converting arguments?

Comment: I think OP wants the other way. `char * = sting s`

Comment: @chris no, i edited my original question, actually I think i am trying to do wha tyou said only backwards

Comment: Use `string::c_str()`. It returns a `const char *`.

Comment: @chris can you elborate a little more please? An example on one of them would help.

Comment: My 0.09 cents. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865668/parse-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help.

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
          std::vector<std::string> params(argv, argv + argc);       
          //Now you can use the command line arguments params[0], params[1] ... 

}
```

Comment: I like your shortcut for converting to vector :)

Answer (score 0):

to convert the command line arguments to strings:

```
std::vector<std::string> args(argc);
for (int i=1; i<argc; ++i)
   args[i] = argv[i];
```

I start at '1' because '0' is the program name:

---

to get them into vars, maybe:

```
// Make sure we're not accessing past the end of the array.
if (argc != 4) {
    std::cout << "Please enter three command line arguments" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

string startCity = argv[1];
string endCity = argv[2];
string fileName = argv[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a `const char *` from a `std::string`, use `std::string::c_str()`.

```
fstream file;
string s = "path\\file.txt";
file.open (s.c_str(), ios::in);
```

Comment: Need it the other way. Edited the original post.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the only other way is like `string s = some_char_array;`, which I mentioned in the comments.

Comment: `cin` or `getline` should work for inputting strings. Passing them to `open` requires `c_str()` for the C-style string.

Comment: How would I do the startCity or endCity? `std::startCity::c_str()` where `string startCity;` has been declared earlier?

Comment: @user1318371, `string startCity = "some city"; const char *c_style_startCity = startCity.c_str();`

Comment: Something doesn't seem right to me, where is the argv[1] supposed to go for startCity and argv[2] for endCity? like I had up there earlier, `string startCity = char * argv[1]` which I know is incorrect but that is what I am trying to do. Thank You for your comments and help. I have tests in the program for the argv[1] and argv[2], i.e. `bool ArgCheck = TestArgs(argv[1],cities,st);
      if(!ArgCheck) {
         throw MyException("Start city not found in map file.");
      }`

Comment: All you need to do to assign a `char *` to a `string` is just say `char *c = "hello"; string s = c;` You don't need any extra `char *`s in there or anything. Saying that fits the `string` constructor that takes a `char *`, so no problems. In this case `argv [x]` is a `char[]`, which works just as well.

Comment: Will this work? `string s = "hello"; char *c = s;` That seems to be what I need. Sorry @chris, not tryin got be a pain.

Comment: You could try `char *c = s.c_str();`. There's one problem with that though. `c_str()` returns a `const char *`. If you **need** the `char *`, you can copy the result into a non-const array and use that.