# What is program -this called and how can I use them in C++?

Tags: c++

This may be a bad question but I would like to know what the `-o` called when you have something like

`g++ -o hello.out hello.cpp`

and how I can implement them in a C++ program

Comment: I think you are messing things here....

Comment: It's called options or switches. As for how to implement it, just parse arguments from main...

Comment: Check out [GCC Command Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_3.html).

Comment: Sorry that it was a bad question, but I have never heard them referred to by name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are [command line arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments).

> A command-line argument or parameter is an item of information provided to a program when it is started. A program can have many command-line arguments that identify sources or destinations of information, or that alter the operation of the program.

The `-x`, `--x` or `/x` forms are generally considered [options or switches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command-line_option).

The program run determines what is actually done; in C/C++ the arguments are directly accessible in the [`argv` parameter](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html) to the main function. There are are also [libraries to make parsing easier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865668/parse-command-line-arguments).

Answer (score 2):

`-o` is an option passed to the compiler `g++`. It let give the name of the file to produce. Here it means "compile file `hello.cpp` to produce a file called `hello.out`".

You can read the manual to find out more: `man g++`

---

If you want to know how to use flags like this in your program, you may eg. refer to [Arguments to main in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176326/arguments-to-main-in-c)

In short: if you define your main function by `int main(int argc, char **argv);`, then a potential `-o`  flag provided by the user, could be read from `argv`