# How to read command line arguments from a text file?

Tags: c++

I have a program that takes in one integer and two strings from a text file   "./myprog < text.txt"  but I want it to be able to do this using command line arguments without the "<", like "./myprog text.txt" where the text file has 3 input values.

```
3 <- integer
AAAAAA <- string1  
AAAAAA <- string2
```

Comment: you don't show any prior research, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865668/parsing-command-line-arguments-in-c

Comment: First step: figure out how to access the command line arguments from within your program. Second step: do something with those arguments (such as treating the first argument as the name of a file). If you haven't done the first step, don't worry about the rest. For now, focus on the task of getting `"X"` when someone invokes your program as `./myprog X`.

Comment: In your favority C++ resource, search for "main parameters" or "main arguments" or "declarations of main function".

Comment: I believe that this topic is always covered in one of the first introductory chapters in every beginner-level C++ textbook, so what textbook are you using, and on which chapter are you on, right now? I'm curious.

Comment: i'm in algorithms..... its been a rough night lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the reading of the parameters must be done solely from the file having it's name, the idiomatic way is, I would say, to use [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

```cpp
std::ifstream ifs("text.txt");
if (!ifs)
    std::cerr << "couldn't open text.txt for reading\n";
std::string line;
std::getline(ifs, line);
int integer = std::stoi(line);
std::getline(ifs, line);
std::string string1 = line;
std::getline(ifs, line);
std::string string2 = line;
```

Because there are little lines in your file, we can allow ourselves some repetition. But as it becomes larger, you might need to read them into a vector:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> arguments;
std::string line;
while (getline(ifs, line))
    arguments.push_back(line);
```

There some optimizations possible, as reusing the line buffer in the first example and using `std::move()`, but they are omitted for clarity.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I needed

Comment: @trab Feel free to mark the answer as correct.