# Set prefix for software in C++ in terminal

Tags: c++, linux, bash, homebrew

I want to make an app in C++ for Linux terminal, but I don't know how to set the prefix. Like, when using homebrew, the prefix is `brew <the command>`. For my app, I want to be `davd <the command>`, how can I make this in C++?

Comment: I think it's `alias` in shell, not related to C++.

Comment: ok , but how do I set an alias ? @Nimrod

Comment: see https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html

Comment: Thx a lot for your help

Comment: There is no magic, `brew` is just an executable/script/function. It is no different from `ls` or `git` or whatever.

Comment: Totally unclear what is asked! Is it about (re)name a file/executable? Create a (sym)link? Alias in the shell? Compile the executable directly with correct filename? Sorry...

Comment: does he not like `a.out`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer (probably) has multiple parts:

- Your application will have to parse the arguments given to it on the command line, which are available inside `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`. There are [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865668/parsing-command-line-arguments-in-c) to do this.
- The name of the executable is set by the compiler, so you have to let it know via the command line or your build configuration file.
- To be able to run an executable without specifying its path, its location must be listed in the $PATH environment variable. On linux, this is commonly done by putting user-built executables in `~/.local/bin` (for your use only, ~ is your home directory) or `/usr/local/bin` (accessible to other users). It could be a symlink to the file in your build directory, manually copied there, or put there by your build system using an install target.